# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe, imageio_ffmpeg, python

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Context:
I am using Ubuntu 20.4 vps and Apache2 for hosting a Deep Learning model using flask.

I need to write a video from images, there i used

```
imageio.mimsave(path, [img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in predictions], fps=fps)
```

When i test it using flask-ngrok it works. But after deployment on flask using WSGI and apache2 server, it gives me this Broken pipe error. Weird!

Error logs of Apache2:

ERROR:model:Exception on / [POST], referer: host ip
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http:///
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/imageio_ffmpeg/_io.py", line 493, in write_frames, referer: host ip
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256]  p.stdin.write(bb), referer: http:///
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe, referer: host ip
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] , referer: http:///
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857233 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:, referer: http://
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857238 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client] , referer: http:///
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857243 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client 3] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http:///
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857250 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app, referer: http:///
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857256 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ]     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http:///
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857261 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http:///
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857266 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857272 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857277 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857294 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857300 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857306 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]   File "/var/www/html/model/model/Model/model.py", line 48, in predict, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857311 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     imageio.mimsave('/home/administrator/model/model/Model/outputs/generated.mp4', [img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in predictions], fps=fps), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857317 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/imageio/core/functions.py", line 418, in mimwrite, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857322 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     writer.append_data(im), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857327 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/imageio/core/format.py", line 502, in append_data, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857332 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     return self._append_data(im, total_meta), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857337 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py", line 574, in _append_data, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857342 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     self._write_gen.send(im), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857347 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/imageio_ffmpeg/_io.py", line 500, in write_frames, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857353 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip]     raise IOError(msg), referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857358 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip] OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857363 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip] , referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857367 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip] FFMPEG COMMAND:, referer: host ip
[Wed Aug 04 16:36:27.857373 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip] /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/imageio_ffmpeg/binaries/ffmpeg-linux64-v4.2.2 -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 256x256 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 20.00 -i - -an -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 25 -v warning /home/administrator/model/model/Model/outputs/generated.mp4, referer: host ip
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip] , referer: http:///
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip] FFMPEG STDERR OUTPUT:, referer:
[wsgi:error] [pid 1029:tid 140257565120256] [client ip] , referer: host ip

Answer (score 0):

Fix:
Linux itself has ffmpeg which is causing error here. It is also written in error logs that ffmpeg version that comes up with linux is outdated and needs to be updated.

use:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

This will hopefully resolve the error. Please comment if you have any other query.